# sortBy descending in Ember property

Tags: ember.js

I'm sorting a collection that is a computed property in my model:

```
collection: function() {
  var entries = this.get('entries');
  return entries.sortBy('prop1', 'prop2');
}.property('entries.@each.prop1', 'entries.@each.prop2')
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to sort descending. That should be easy, right?

Ember 1.13

Comment: Well call reverse on the results. entries.sortBy('prop1', 'prop2').reverse(); From looking through the code, i think thats all u can do. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.2.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/enumerable.js#L1044

Comment: @blessenm This worked for me, but it seems limited. Maybe I want one ascending and one descending for example.

Comment: yes its just a quick fix. Miguels approach is the way to go.

Comment: @blessenm I would certainly go that way if I could get it to work. When I try Miguel's approach, no filtering happens.

Comment: Can u reproduce ur error in emberjs.jsbin.com. Here is a working example http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mucube/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 17):

You can use `Ember.computed.sort` macro: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort

Example:

```
entriesSorting: ['prop1:desc', 'prop2:desc'],
collection: Ember.computed.sort('entries', 'entriesSorting')
```

Unrelated, but relevant: the usage of `Ember.computed` over the `.property` prototype extention is recommended.

UPDATE:
Here is a twiddle of this working: https://ember-twiddle.com/19ff8c56f1c13512bdc8

Comment: Strange, I can't get that to work for me. Looks nicer, though

Comment: @EricWilson I added an ember twiddle to demonstrate this working

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that I was doing this in the model, not the controller? I'll see if I can do an ember-twiddle, never done that.

Comment: Maybe your issue is with hasMany relationships. The ember twiddle proves it works. I'd be glad to help you if you provide me some more context. Ideally a non-working twiddle.

Comment: @EricWilson Did this help you? Can this be accepted?

Comment: I appreciate the work you have put into this answer, but at this time I have no idea whether this answer was helpful to me or not. This project is on hiatus for personal reasons. I may return to it in June or July. I typically do accept answers, but there are times when I don't and I hope that you will be able to move on if that needs to be the case here.

Comment: There is evidence that this answer works with the twiddle. Also, I think the complexity level here is low enough to deduce the correctness or incorrectness of it. With that being said, my life will go on normally. :) No problem.

Comment: @miguelcobain - Does this code need to be run in controller or it can be done in ember component as well.

Comment: @whyAto8 Anything that extends Ember.Object, including Controllers and Components.

Comment: @miguelcobain - As in this example, the "entries" is an array of objects and the field "name" is used for sorting. In my scenario, I have an array of objects, and inside each object I have another array of objects and want to sort based on the field inside that. For e.g. the structure is             {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Eric',
      list :[
        {displayName: "alpha"},
        {displayName: "mike"}
      ]
    }   So, i want to sort on basis of displayName of first object only inside list array. Is that possible?